# Gridview with radio column, radio id problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview, and I put a radio column for it. But radio ids are not unique.
I've read 
http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/tutorial-51-cs.aspx
http://shawpnendu.blogspot.com/2009/02/problem-to-group-radio-button-across.html
https://web.archive.org/web/20210510012500/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122602-1.aspx
but they are complicated.
Do you have other solution, with c# code behind? I've also tried to give unique id with a function from code behind, but ID='<%# function(...) %>' is not allowed.
Thank you in advance

there is gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView_stLists"
              runat="server"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CellPadding="3"
              BorderStyle="NotSet"
              CssClass="table_layout"
              Width="500">
           <RowStyle CssClass="table_body" />
              <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="20">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:RadioButton ID="rdBtn_stdl" runat="server"
                             OnCheckedChanged="rdBtn_stdl_CheckedChanged"
                             AutoPostBack="True"
                             GroupName="stdl" value='<%# Eval("uri") %>' />
                     </ItemTemplate>
```

I think radios must have different IDs in ID="rdBtn_stdl" section

Comment: You need to read the first link.  It has the answer right there!  You say you read it, but you did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good method at:
http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/tutorial-51-cs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what your question is, but here goes.

If you need to find a RadioButton in a GridViewRow, first get the row, then use FindControl()

```
GridViewRow myRow = GridView1.Rows[index];
RadioButton myRadioButton = (RadioButton)myRow.FindControl("nameOfRadioButton")
```

You can do that in reverse (if you need to handle the event RadioButton1_CheckedChanged, for example) by first casting the object sender to RadioButton, then casting RadioButton.Parent.Parent to GridViewRow, from which you can get the index.

Question:

Is the column you added a Template Column, in which you places a RadioButton?  My two solutions will only work in this case.

Comment: Thanks, your answer learned me. However in my web, mutiple radiobuttons can be selected. I think it is because they have same ID

Answer (score 0):

The radio buttons need to have the same `name` attribute.  **Not** unique.  This is how the browser knows how to group them.

Comment: it is runat server. but multiple selections are allowed.
thanks for answer